# Android TabLayout - Navigate betweend activities

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, tabs

I want to know if it is possible to navigate between more than one activity per Tab in a Tablayout. If my Layout would look like this:

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-HITXAdYDGkM/UfIVbwTSnOI/AAAAAAAAAm8/B-T_lfWX030/s400/tab3.png

And the activity which is shown in Tab1 would call another acitvity by StartActivity(intent, activity.class) via buttonclick - would this work? Will the TabLayout right unter the ActionBar still be there?

Comment: Refer [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a TabLayout, use the Actionbar as described here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: The problem is that i already have a lot of activities and this method needs fragments instead of normal acitivities...

Comment: Then use Fragments :)

Comment: I've read some things about Fragments now, but is it a lot of work to change ~20 activities? I also transfer some informations between the activities and i couldnt find something about this possibility in fragments. also starting fragments on button click etc seems to be pretty complicated..